# How to Allow AWS Access from Batch Job to S3 on Another Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-batch

I have a batch job in account `A` and bucket in account `B`. When my job requests `s3:GetBucketLocation`, it returns `Access Denied`.

I've set up such permissions on my batch job (account `A`):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-in-account-B",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-in-account-B/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and bucket permissions (account `B`):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        ...,
        {
            "Sid": "123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{{numbers}}:role/{{name}}"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-in-account-B",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-in-account-B/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

These permissions don't work.

Comment: lol. `{{numbers}}` is not numbers. Its `Account Id`.

Answer (score 0):

are u trying to access the bucket from inside the batch job after its started running or are you trying to hook up the bucket file landing events to trigger batch jobs???

i am assuming its the former. in that case bucket policy should be enough to grant cross account access. it might be an issue with the actual arn you are putting in the bucket policy.

it might not be "arn:aws:iam::{{numbers}}:role/{{name}}" ...
you might have to put assume-role in there or put the instance profile arn. it depends. how you've set up the job. where does the job get its credentials. from the IAM role attached to the underlying instance (via instance profile) or ecs task role (basically role for your batch container)

inside your job you can do something like

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
```

try to grant bucket access to the arn printed from that command minus the session name
(the last bit of the arn)

Answer (score -1):

The bucket B's policy should include permission for user from account A to access it, something like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountQ:user/AccountAUserName"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```